# Adding to Dynamic Array C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

I know this might look like a duplicate question; but what I am looking for is a code-specific answer to my problem (not extrapolating off another answer).  I am looking to add to a dynamic array in c, yet I am having issues assigning to the last element in the array (when I use gdb the values are assigned to my array at first, but disappear later on for no apparent reason).  Here is my code:

```
typedef struct Server {
char* name;
pid_t pid;
} Server;

//global variables
int num_servers;
Server* servers;

//code inside a function and a WHILE loop
resizeArray();
//create struct
Server s = createServer(args[3], id);
//add to array
insertServer(s);
++num_servers;

//code for allocating memory for array
int resizeArray(){
//initialize array if needed
    if( num_servers == 0 ){
        servers = (Server*) malloc(1 * sizeof(Server));
        //TODO check malloc
    }
    //realloc for one more server instance on array
    else{
        servers = realloc(servers, (num_servers+1) * sizeof(Server));
        //TODO check realloc
    }
}

//basically a constructor
Server createServer(char* name, pid_t id){
    Server s;
    s.name = malloc(strlen(name) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(s.name, name);
    s.pid = id;
    return s;
}

//adds server to array (always last element)
int insertServer(Server serv){
    servers[num_servers - 1] = serv;
    //servers[num_servers - 1].name = serv.name;
    //servers[num_servers - 1].pid = serv.pid;
    return 0; //TODO probably change return type to void
}
```

Yet for whatever reason, this code doesn't actually make the last element in the array hold the values I want (when I debug it looks like the memory is allocated, but servers->pid and servers->name isn't what I set it to).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't initialise `num_servers` before you use it - it could have any starting value

Comment: Initialize your variables: `int num_servers;` -> `int num_servers = 0;`. Not directly related: 1) calling `realloc` for each new entry is very inefficient, 2) if you initialize `servers` to `NULL` you don't need the disrimination between `malloc` and `realloc`, you just can call `servers = realloc(servers, (num_servers+1) * sizeof(Server));` because `realloc(NULL, foo)` is equivalent to `malloc(foo)`.

Comment: Reiew `s.name = malloc(strlen(name) * sizeof(char));
  strcpy(s.name, name);`.  How much memory does `s.name` need?

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments; does anyone have any idea why my array (servers) does not contain the struct I created and add to it?